# run script if user logged in not working?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    $somevar= "something";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var somevar2 = <?php echo $value; ?>;
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

I put the code inside `<head>`, the console shows `somevar2` is undefined, I was expecting the script don't run because it put in a scope where it execute only when user is logged in. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: where is $value defined?

Comment: Most likely the error is coming from further down your code, where you try to _access_ `somevar2`, but it doesn’t exist because the shown `<script>` block has not been written into the HTML output for the not logged-in user.

Comment: This is because `$value` is not declared anywhere in your code.

Comment: @WayneC in another file.php which when execute when the ajax query sent. Now I think it's because the ajax is slower than the script?

Comment: is value defined somewhere?. does $value contain something that will be evaluated as valid javascript? have you turned on all errors and warnings in php?

Comment: @JavierNeyra no error in php

Comment: It work jst find the session is set, but my if condition failed, because it executed even the session is not set

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    $somevar= "something";
?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var somevar2 = <?php echo $somevar; ?>;
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

That should do the job. My guess is that you just forgot to change the variable echoed.

Comment: That is Right. Danny. +1

Comment: This still isn't right, the result wouldn't be as expected. This would result in: `var somevar2 = something;` and `something` won't be defined in  JS. This should be changed to: `var somevar2 = <?php echo json_encode($somevar); ?>`

Comment: no.. the somevar2 is defined at another file (process.php) where I used ajax.. what I want is, if the user is not logged in, don't run the script. possible?